# GREP How do I search for words that contain specific letters (one or more times)?

Tags: grep

I'm using the operating systems dictionary file to scan. I'm creating a java program to allow a user to enter any concoction of letters to find words that contain those letters. How would I do this using grep commands?

Comment: Do you want to find words that contain *any* of those letters, *all* of those letters, or *only* those letters?

Comment: @GregHewgill I want to find ALL for one option and only those letters for another option

Comment: You might find the following helpful: [How to use the Grep command in Terminal to cheat at Scrabble and Words With Friends](http://www.edibleapple.com/2011/04/13/how-to-use-the-grep-command-in-terminal-to-cheat-at-scrabble-and-words-with-friends/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To find words that contain *only* the given letters:

```
grep -v '[^aeiou]' wordlist
```

The above filters out the lines in `wordlist` that *don't* contain any characters except for those listed. It's sort of using a double negative to get what you want. Another way to do this would be:

```
grep '^[aeiou]+$' wordlist
```

which searches the whole line for a sequence of one or more of the selected letters.

To find words that contain *all* of the given letters is a bit more lengthy, because there may be other letters in between the ones we want:

```
cat wordlist | grep a | grep e | grep i | grep o | grep u
```

<sub>(Yes, there is a useless use of `cat` above, but the symmetry is better this way.)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You can use a single `grep` to solve the last problem in Greg's answer, provided your `grep` supports PCRE.  (Based on [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15393882/regex-to-match-at-least-2-digits-2-letters-in-any-order-in-a-string), boiled down a bit)

```
grep -P "(?=.*a)(?=.*e)(?=.*i)(?=.*o)(?=.*u)" wordlist
```

The positive lookahead means it will match anything with an "a" anywhere, and an "e" anywhere, and.... etc etc.