# GREP How do I only retrieve words with only the specified letters?

Tags: java, regex, grep

I wish to figure out how to do the following with grep (given a dictionary file to grep from)

1. Find only words that **CONTAIN ONLY** the following characters: `dgo`

   Example: dog, god
2. Finda any words that contains **ALL** the following characters (at least once): `dgo`

   Example: dogma, togaed etc...

Comment: If you can do both, I would greatly appreciate it :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [GREP How do I search for words that contain specific letters (one or more times)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10526233/grep-how-do-i-search-for-words-that-contain-specific-letters-one-or-more-times)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only:

```
 ^[god]+$
```

All:

```
 (?=.*g)(?=.*o)(?=.*d)
```

Comment: how does the 'all' one work. are you piping into one another? can you provide full grep command for the later one. Thanks

Comment: @stackoverflow That’s a Java-style regex, which is really Perl-style, so you need `grep  -P` for it.

Answer (score 1):

```
1. egrep "^[dgo]+$" /usr/dict/words
2. egrep "(d.*((g.*o.*)|(o.*g.*)))|(g.*((d.*o.*)|(o.*d.*)))|(o.*((d.*g.*)|(g.*d.*)))" /usr/dict/words
```

Answer (score 0):

Second:

```
 grep d /usr/dict/words | grep o | grep  g
```