# How do I find words with all the specified characters, with repetition?

Tags: regex

Is there a way to find the words containing all the given characters, include the repetitive ones, with regular expression? For example, I want to find all words from list

```
aabc, abbc, bbbc, aaac, aaab, baac, caab, abca
```

that contain exactly one 'b' and two 'a's, i.e. `aabc`, `baac`, `caab`, and `abca` (but NOT `aaab` as it has an additional 'a'). Word length doesn't matter.

While this question

[GREP How do I only retrieve words with only the specified letters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10566812/grep-how-do-i-only-retrieve-words-with-only-the-specified-letters)

could give me some hint, I wasn't able to extend it so it will find repeative characters.

I am just playing with re module from Python, but there is no restrcition on language / tool for the question.

EDIT:

A better example / usecase would be: Given a list of words, show only those that contain all the letters entered by a user, e.g. I would like to find all words containing exactly one 'a', two 'd's and one 's'. Is this something regex capable of? (I already know how to do it without regex.)

Comment: What programming language/regex flavor are you using?

Comment: @MattBall it's a general question, not really bounded to a specifical tool (yet). I'll update the question a bit, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If your regex flavor supports lookaheads, then you can use this:

```
\b(?=.*b)(?=([^a]*a){2}[^a]*\b)[abc]+\b
```

This requires at least one b and exactly 2 a's, and allows only a, b and c in the string. If you want to require exactly one b and exactly 4 characters in total, use this:

```
\b(?=[^b]*b[^b]*\b)(?=([^a]*a){2}[^a]*\b)[abc]{4}\b
```

Comment: To whomever downvoted the answer, next time please leave a comment on the reason **and** I fixed the mistake.

Comment: I don't get why your answer (and that from anubhava) got downvoted either. Your answers might not be the most elegant ones -- if this _could_ be done more elegantly with regex -- but they are surely correct ones.

Comment: @Metaphox, mine **did** have a slight mistake and did not capture all your cases, so it was kind of justified. Still, I prefer downvoters to explain their reasons. (I also fixed that mistake now). For your other question, I don't think there is a much easier solution and I don't even find it really inelegant. Using lookaheads separates your different requirements into manageable blocks, and is usually the go-to approach if one has several different requirements for a string (e.g. safe-password requirements)

Answer (score 0):

To match exactly 2 a's and 1 b (in any order) in your input string use this regex:

```
(?=^(?:[^a]*a){2}[^a]*$)(?=^[^b]*b[^b]*$)^.+$
```

[Here is a live demo for you](http://www.rubular.com/r/ANsuPNaIEi).

Comment: many thanks! i wonder if there's a, uh, more elegent way tho? as i might have to manually count how many 'a's has the user entered. that's not too hard, but still I wonder if I can do this a bit more concisely?

Comment: I would request you to provide more context to your problem in your question. Like you said `i might have to manually count how many 'a's has the user entered` - Are you working on user provided inputs here? Some details will definitely help here.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, but I am not really working on any certain problem, just trying to figure out more what regex is capable for. I am just imagine possbilities, like 'what if I do not know how many "a"s will I need to find', thus the user input scenario.

Comment: See IMO users should only provide input data not the rules of validation. Rules of validation (i.e. regex) should be part of your application logic and if that's the case your logic would already know  what validations need to be applied on input data. RegEx have lot of strengths but some limitations also (esp. input is irregular like HTML text).

Comment: Thanks for the advice. What brought me to this question is the game 'Letterpress' on iOS. The user will need to select several letters from a matrix to make a combination, and the programm will validate if the combination is a valid word. I was simply thinking if I can check if the letters from user input are contained in a word.

Comment: Too be honest I wouldn't use regex to check presence of user entered individual characters in a word. Reason is that just to build right regex you will have to loop through user input string char by char anyway. It is not impossible to do it via regex but I think in this case its not worth it.

Comment: 'just to build right regex you will have to loop through user input string char by char' -- exactly what I was thinking. Many thanks!